# Console.log() inside useEffect hook in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Iam novice to react native programming (programming in genera) and for a project i have created a functional react component to display list of events data. In this component i want to sort the events first based on year and month and then based on days within these days. I created the algorithm for sorting the events and pasted the code for this on the useEffect hook of this react component. This component code is given below

```
import { ActivityIndicator, Dimensions, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { ScrollView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { EventContext } from '../context/EventContext';
import EventCard from '../components/EventCard';
import { headerStyleOptions } from '../styles/headerStyleOptions';
import H1 from '../styles/styledcomponents/H1';
import { PRIMARYCOLOR } from '../styles/colors';
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';


const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');
const monthsArray = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
let eventSorted: Object[] = [];


const EventListScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { state: events } = useContext(EventContext);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
 
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions(headerStyleOptions('drawer', navigation, 'EVENTS LIST',
      { rightIcon1: 'add-circle', rightIconOnPress1: () => { navigation.navigate('EventCreateScreen') }, textColor: PRIMARYCOLOR, fontFamilly: 1, backgroundColor: 'black' }))
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    eventSorted = [];
    events.map(ev => {
      const date = new Date(ev.deadlinedate)
      let key = `${date.getFullYear()}${date.getMonth()}`;
      const dayKey = `${date.getDate()}`
      if (eventSorted.length == 0) {
        let obj: Object = {}
        obj[key] = {};
        eventSorted.push(obj)
        eventSorted[0][key][dayKey] = []
        eventSorted[0][key][dayKey].push(ev);
      } else {
        const check = eventSorted.findIndex(evso => ((Object.keys(evso)[0] == key)))
        if (check == -1) {
          let obj: Object = {}
          obj[key] = {};

          for (let i = 0; i < eventSorted.length; i++) {

            if (date.getFullYear() == parseInt(Object.keys(eventSorted[i])[0].slice(0, 4))) {
              if (date.getMonth() < parseInt(Object.keys(eventSorted[i])[0].slice(4))) {
                eventSorted.splice(i, 0, obj)
                eventSorted[i][key][dayKey] = []

                eventSorted[i][key][dayKey].push(ev)
                i = i + 1;
                break;
              } else {
                if (i == eventSorted.length - 1) {
                  eventSorted.splice(i + 1, 0, obj)
                  eventSorted[i + 1][key][dayKey] = []
                  eventSorted[i + 1][key][dayKey].push(ev)
                  break;
                }
              }
            } else if (date.getFullYear() < parseInt(Object.keys(eventSorted[i])[0].slice(0, 4))) {
              eventSorted.splice(i, 0, obj)
              eventSorted[i][key][dayKey] = []
              eventSorted[i][key][dayKey].push(ev)
              break;
            }else{
              if(i==eventSorted.length-1){
                eventSorted.splice(i+1,0,obj)
                eventSorted[i+1][key][dayKey] = [];
                eventSorted[i+1][key][dayKey].push(ev)
                break;
              }
            }

          }

        } else {
          if (dayKey in eventSorted[check][key]) {
            eventSorted[check][key][dayKey].push(ev)
          } else {
            Object.entries(eventSorted[check][key]).forEach(([k, value], index) => {
              if (parseInt(k) > parseInt(dayKey)) {
                let keyValues = Object.entries(eventSorted[check][key]);
                keyValues.splice(index, 0, [dayKey, []])
                eventSorted[check][key] = Object.fromEntries(keyValues)
                eventSorted[check][key][dayKey].push(ev)
                return false;
              } else {
                if (index == Object.keys(eventSorted[check][key]).length - 1) {
                  let keyValues = Object.entries(eventSorted[check][key]);
                  keyValues.splice(index + 1, 0, [dayKey, []])
                  eventSorted[check][key] = Object.fromEntries(keyValues)
                  eventSorted[check][key][dayKey].push(ev)
                  return false;
                }
              }
            }
            )
          }
        }
      }
    })
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log('finished2')
      setLoading(false)
    },0)
    console.log('finished1')
    console.log('eventSorted', eventSorted)
  }, [])




  return (
    <View style={{ height,backgroundColor:'white'}}>
      <StatusBar style='inverted' />
      {loading ?
        <View style={{flex:1,alignItems:'center',justifyContent:'center'}}>
        <ActivityIndicator size='large'/>
        </View>
        :
        // <Text>Hello</Text>
        <ScrollView>
          {
            eventSorted.map(ev => {
              return Object.keys(ev).map(key => {

                let month: string;

                month = monthsArray[parseInt(key.toString().slice(4))]

                return (
                  <View>
                    <H1  key={`${month} ${key.substring(0,4)}`} style={{ alignSelf: 'center', fontSize: 22, paddingVertical: '2%' }}>{month} {key.substring(0, 4)}</H1>
                    <View>
                      {
                        Object.keys(ev[key]).map(k => {
                          let dateheight = height * .2 * Object.keys(ev[key][k]).length
                          return (
                            <View key={`${month} ${key.substring(0,4)} ${k}`}>
                              <View style={{ position: 'absolute', height: dateheight, width: 50, borderBottomWidth: 1, borderRightWidth: 1, backgroundColor: 'white' }}>
                                <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center', fontSize: 20, top: 30 }}>{k}</Text>
                              </View>

                              {
                                ev[key][k].map(so => {
                                  return <EventCard eventid={so.eventid} key={so.eventid}/>
                                })
                              }
                            </View>
                          )
                        }
                        )
                      }
                    </View>

                  </View>
                )
              })
            })
          }

          <View style={{ alignSelf: 'center', backgroundColor: 'white', width: '100%' }}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 100 }}></Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      }
    </View>
  )
}


export default EventListScreen

const styles = StyleSheet.create({})
```

After running this code when i open this page there is a time lag to display the sorted event list. For checking where the code is taking time. I put a console.log  on multiple locations in the code. You can see two console.logs at the end of the useEffect in adjacent two line which are `console.log('finished1')` and `console.log('eventSorted', eventSorted)`. After inserting these two console logs when  I run the page, I saw that finished1 is logging to the console immediately after navigating to this page but the next console.log is getting delayed like it is being awaited and it gets console logged and view gets populated at almost the same time. Can anyone tell me why eventSorted console log is behaving is it being awaited on?

Also When i interchange the position of the first console.log and second console.log. Then this `console.log('finished1')` is logging after a long delay after `console.log('eventSorted',eventSorted)` is output to the terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be experiencing an adverse effect of not clearing `setTimeout` inside of `useEffect` - which is known to produce [strange behavior](https://upmostly.com/tutorials/settimeout-in-react-components-using-hooks).

Instead of

```
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log('finished2')
      setLoading(false)
    },0)
    console.log('finished1')
    console.log('eventSorted', eventSorted)
```

try

```
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Hello, World!"), 3000);
      setLoading(false)
    },1000)
    console.log('finished1')
    console.log('eventSorted', eventSorted)
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
```

Also notice I have set the delay in `setTimeout` to 1 second (you had the delay set to 0 seconds in your code above).

Comment: event after doing this, it is showing the same behavior as before